# What is the proper term for the linear, surface area, and volume components in density equations?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, terminology

Say one is looking at charge density. Linear charge density would be given by
$$
\lambda = \frac Q \ell
$$
surface charge density would by given by
$$
\sigma = \frac Q A
$$
and volume charge density would be given by
$$
\rho = \frac Q V
$$
The left term could generally just be called "the density", but does the inverse component have a general name?

Comment: The volume per unit mass is the _specific volume_ so I guess the volume per unit charge would be the _specific charge volume_. However I have never heard this term used.